# React Native Expo Publishing

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there a way to ensure the Expo project page is not publicly accessible? I've tried changing the privacy setting in the app.json but it still remains possible to reach it.

Comment: Did my Answer help you? Please provide some Feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you expo publish your app you can go to `expo.io` and logg into your account.

Then you need to press your user icon (top right on expo.io). There you select "snacks" and then go to "projects". In projects you can see the projects that you have created.

> If you click on the options-button you can set the privacy to private and vice versa.